# MATLAB: How to paste fig Into excel, then save and close excel file?

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, save

I generated an excel file in MATLAB and successfully saved and closed it using this:

```
    invoke(Workbook,'Save')
    invoke(Excel,'Quit');
    delete(Excel);
    clear Excel;
```

But then when I add a figure to that excel file using **PlotInExcel**, I can't save and close the file using that same code again.  Here is **PlotInExcel**:

```
    function PlotInExcel
       x= {1:10};
       a= cell2mat(x);
       y= {1:10};
       b= cell2mat(y);
       %............plotting......................
       plot(a,b);
       xlabel('X Values');
       ylabel('Y Values');
       print -dmeta;   %.................Copying to clipboard
       FILE  = 'C:DATA.xlsx';
       Range='OL14';
       %.............excel COM object...........................................
             Excel = actxserver ('Excel.Application');
     Excel.Visible = 1;
     if ~exist(FILE,'file')
           ExcelWorkbook=Excel.Workbooks.Add;
            ExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(FILE);
           ExcelWorkbook.Close(false);
     end
     invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Open',FILE); %Open the file
     ActiveSheet  = Excel.ActiveSheet;
     ActiveSheetRange  = get(ActiveSheet,'Range',Range);
    ActiveSheetRange.Select;
     ActiveSheetRange.PasteSpecial; %.................Pasting the figure to the selected location

    %-----------------------------------end of function"PlotInExcel----------
```

How do I get MatLab to save this file now and exit?  The aforementioned code at top doesn't work now.  Is there someway to add code to the function? or can/should I Save/Close the file outside the function back in my script?

Comment: Maybe, the problem in here: "FILE  = 'C:DATA.xlsx';"? You are forget '\' ?

Comment: Thanks, but that was a typo in my query only...not part of the actual 
 code.  You are correct, the line should have read “ FILE  = 'C:\DATA.xlsx';“.  But that doesn’t (didn’t) solve the prob or answer how to Save and Quit excel.

Comment: Do you seen that? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-matlab-application-as-an-automation-client.html

Comment: Thanks!  Let me check that out. Looks like slightly different code.  May work.

Comment: Hmm...I still can't get PlotInExcel to Save, Close, and Quit so that I can add more data to my excel file and a second figure later in the script.  The Excel file hangs open after the first pass through PlotInExcel

Comment: Unfortunately I havent time for test it, but I can propose you to check this solution: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96794-how-can-i-open-an-existing-excel-file-and-communicate-with-it-using-activex

Comment: Drat! I still can't get the PlotInExcel fnx to Save and Quit so that I can continue the script's actions.  I tried adding                                  invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Save');
invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Quit');
delete(Excel);
clear Excel;                    to the PlotInExcel fnx but it stops right at "invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Save')"

Answer (score 0):

With enough bashing around, I was finally able to answer my own question.  I'm posting the resolution here in the event anyone else has this problem.  I removed the lines at the beginning because they just produced a test figure.  The function below assumes you have your own figure you want to paste into an excel spreadsheet.  BTW, you must have your figure saved to the clipboard before running this function.

```
function PlotInExcel
   
   FILE  = 'C:\DATA.xlsx';     %identify the name and location of your excel spreadsheet
   Range='R1';                 %select where you want your figure pasted in the speadsheet (cell ID)
   %.............excel COM object............................................................................
         Excel = actxserver ('Excel.Application');
 Excel.Visible = 1;
 if ~exist(FILE,'file')
       ExcelWorkbook=Excel.Workbooks.Add;
       ExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(FILE);
       ExcelWorkbook.Close(false);
 end
 invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Open',FILE); %Open the file
 ActiveSheet  = Excel.ActiveSheet;
 ActiveSheetRange  = get(ActiveSheet,'Range',Range);
 ActiveSheetRange.Select;
 ActiveSheetRange.PasteSpecial; %.................Pasting the figure to the selected location
  Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save     % Now save the workbook
     if eq(Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved,1)
         Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close;
     else
         Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save;
     end
     invoke(Excel, 'Quit');    % Quit Excel    
     delete(Excel);            % End process
end
```